# How to unit test artifacts that use a domain object with a sequence in it?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I am writing tests (using Grails 2.0.4/Spock/Build-Test-Data plugin) for my services that work with a domain object that has a sequence in it. The challenge is that the sequence is not working inside the unit tests so i am wondering on how to tackle this?

Example: domain object

```
class Transaction {
    Long transactionId          // unique auto generated transaction id

    // .. code omitted

    static mapping = {
        // sequence generator for handing out unique transaction id's
        transactionId generator:'sequence', params:[initial_value: 50, sequence:'seq_transaction_id']
    }

}
```

Example: test

```
@Build(Transaction)
@TestFor(Transaction)
class TransactionSpec extends Specification {
    def "simple test"() {
        when:
        Transaction transaction = Transaction.build()
        transaction.save()

        then:
        true
    }
}
```

The test will simply fail because the transactionId inside the domain object may not be nullable. The sequence in the domain class does not work as expected and returns null. 
Am i missing something? Or are there any other ways i can get the sequence working as expected in a unit test?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your test is an anti-pattern. The then: true block is a huge no-no. What are you trying to test? What is the purpose of this unit test? How can this test ever fail?